# How to Prove n! is unbounded from above

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I want to show that n! is an unbounded sequence from above. I have that the definition of an unbounded sequence is--

A sequence Xn is unbounded from above if for all m ∈ R, there exists an n ∈ N s.t. Xn > m.

Will setting m = 0 make this statement hold true? I am thinking 0 because n! is never 0 or negative. Let me know if this is the right way to think about this, thank you.

Comment: You don't get to pick $m$. Someone else gives you an $m$, it could be any value, and you have to produce an $n$ that satisfies the required conditions.

Comment: You need to show it is true for *all* $m$.  Showing it is true for $m \le 0$ is trivial as $1! > 0\ge m$.  And for $m < 1$ it's equally trivial $1! = 1 > m$. But you are spinning wheels if you do all these case.  If $m < 6$ then $3! > m$ and that includes $m=0, m< 0, 0< m<1, m=1, 1<m<2, etc$.  No you just have to prove it for the *big* cases.

Comment: It's best to assume you know nothing at all about $m$.  But you can always find an $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $n > m$ (do you know why).  And $n! \ge n$ (do you know why) and so $n! \ge n > m$.

Comment: @fleablood thank you for your comments. for always being able to find an n>m, is it because of the Archimedean property (I could be completely wrong)?

Comment: Yes, it is the archimedean property.  $1 > 0$ so for any $m$ there is a natural number $n$ so that $n\times 1 = n > m$.  That's it.

Comment: Of course, the archimedean property is not an axiom.  And the proof of it is essential equivalent to the naturals being unbounded. (Pf: if the weren't a sup would exist. Call it $a$. Let $e=\frac 12 < 1$.  Then $a-e$ is not an upper bound so there exists a natural $n: a-e < n \le a$.  But then $n+1$ is an integer so so $n+1 > a-e + 1 > a$ contradicting $a$ is a sup.)

Comment: I see, thank you. For the n! ≥ n part, is it not because n! is an increasing sequence? A bit confused on that part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m\in\mathbb{R}.$ Define $n=|\lceil m \rceil|+1,$ and you can see that $0<n\in\mathbb{N}.$ We get that $$n!\geq n>|\lceil m \rceil|\geq \lceil m \rceil\geq m.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n>2$

We can see $3!=6\gt3$

Now assume $n!>n$

$$
n!>n\Rightarrow n!+n\cdot n!\gt n+1\Rightarrow(n+1)!>n+1
$$

So we have by induction for all $n>2\quad n!>n$

We can see that for any large $n\quad T_n>n$

So the sequence is unbounded above

Note: $n!>n$ is pretty obvious but i figured you wanted a rigorous

Comment: Just one note: You also need to check that all noninteger upper bounds are ruled out, so you need to start with $m\in \mathbb{R}$ then deal with, e.g., the ceiling of $m$ and proceed that way.

Comment: Ah yes that would be proper mb